# Перевод int в byte?

Tags: java

Как переводится (обрезается) int до размера byte?

Где-то вычитал, что от int отнимается 128 пока число не войдет в диапазон -128...127 и потом отнимается еще раз. То есть во втором примере мы зашли в диапазон (104) и отняли 128 еще раз, до значения -24; а в первом примере мы зашли в диапазон (1) и остановились. Почему так?

```
int a = (byte)257;
```

> Вывод: a = 1;

```
int b = (byte)1000;
```

> Вывод: b = -24;

UPD:
Прошло 4 года и 4 месяца, но конкретного ответа я так и не получил :)

**уточняю вопрос**

int x = 257 в двоичном виде равен

> 00000000_00000000_00000001_00000001

кастуем int к byte: отбрасываем 3 крайних байта от

> 00000000_00000000_00000001_00000001

остается 00000001 что в десятичном виде равно 1

**Результат**:

```
int a = (byte)257;
```

> Вывод: a = 1;

int x = 1000 в двоичном виде равен

> 00000000_00000000_00000011_11101000

кастуем int к byte: отбрасываем 3 крайних байта от

> 00000000_00000000_00000011_11101000

остается 11101000 , здесь крайняя левая единичка отвечает за знак, мы фактически переводим в десятичный вид двоичное число 1101000 что равно 104, плюс не забываем про единичку обозначающую минус, получается -104.
Вопрос данной темы:

**ОТКУДА ВЗЯЛОСЬ ЧИСЛО -24**

Comment: Просто. Младшие 8 бит (один байт) 4-х байтового int-а перемещаются в 8-ми битный (1 байт) byte

Comment: Ничего ни от чего не отнимается. Просто берутся младшие 8 бит числа и их значение присваивается байту. Если старший из этих битов оказался единицей, то байт считается отрицательным. Посмотрите на двоичную запись числа 1000 и почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дополнительный_код

Comment: «плюс не забываем про единичку обозначающую минус, получается -104» — неверно. Это не просто минус, это **дополнительный код**, ссылка на который уже приведена в комментарии выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему там ничего не отнимается, а просто обрезаются левые 3 байта.

257 в двоичном представлении типа int = 0b0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0001__0000_0001 (тип int имеет размер 4 байта).
При привидении к типу byte левые 3 байта отбрасываются и остается один байт: 0b0000_0001.

0b0000_0001 = 1.

Соответственно то же самое и с 1000 = 0b0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0011__1110_1000

После приведения:
0b1110_1000 = -24;

Для большего понимания:

0b - префикс целочисленного литерала в двоичном представлении;

В целочисленных типах **byte**, **short**, **int**, **long** положительные и отрицательные числа закодированы ***дополнительным кодом***. Самый крайний левый бит так же является битом знака.
Подробнее здесь https://microkontroller.ru/programmirovanie-mikrokontrollerov-avr/pryamoy-obratnyiy-dopolnitelnyiy-kod-dvoichnogo-chisla/?amp=1

Примеры:

0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000 = 0;

0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0001 = 1;

0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0011 = 3;

0111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111 = максимальное число;

1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111 = -1;

1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1100 = -4;

1000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000 = минимальное число;

Грубо говоря, берем любое положительное число в двоичном представлении, инвертируем биты и получаем отрицательное число аналогичное тому, если бы мы к положительному числу в десятичном представлении прибавили единицу и поставили минус к результату:
0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000 = 0

…инвертируем…

1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111 = -1

аналогично: 0 + 1 = 1 = -1;

0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0011 = 3

…инвертируем…

1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1111__1111_1100 = - 4

аналогично: 3 + 1 = 4 = -4;

Comment: да, именно так и происходит. просто отбрасываются байты. Но так как в таких языках как java не принято сильно говорить о байта, люди иногда придумывают другие объяснения. С какими то вычитаниями по кругу.

Comment: @KoVadim, как раз таки в тех языках, где принято говорить о байтах и придумывают объяснения с  вычитаниями/прибавлениями по кругу. Например, C, [n1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.3.1.3/2: `if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.` Потому что наивное отбрасывание битов не сработает на не two's complement машине. Ну и в C++ никто [байты не отбрасывает](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3).

Comment: `А вот отрицательные числа закодированы обратным кодом` Это не [обратный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (_ones' complement_), а [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (_two's complement_).

Comment: @wololo - да, стандарт с++ особая штука. Хочет покрыть всякие странные-странные кейсы и платформы. Поэтому они часто так и изголяются. Но "отбрасывать байты" и взятие по модулю в 2 степени n (как написано по ссылке) в случае положительных чисел - это точно одно и тоже. Хотя, как они тут умудрились добавить 2 в степени.... ума не приложу. или все таки бит у нас в двух состояниях может быть (тут сарказм, ведь размер байта не устанавливается точно).

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за поправку!

Answer (score 1):

Тип byte, как и любой другой тип, "проходит" по кругу.
Пример:

```
int a = (byte) 127;
```

> 127

```
int a = (byte) 128;
```

> -128

```
int a = (byte) 129;
```

> -127

...

```
int a = (byte) 257;
```

> 1

Таким образом, когда бы дойдете до 1000, что после N кругов в результат вернут -24.

Comment: Разве не идет обрез битов? https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1945-rasshirenie-i-suzhenie-primitivnihkh-tipov

Comment: @MikeMclaren что вас конкретно не устраивает? мы можете отредактировать ответ

Answer (score 0):

Знание нескольких принципов освобождает от знания многих фактов.

Предлагаю краткий теоретический минимум для понимания вопроса, вместо вычисления той самой формулы про:

> от int отнимается 128 пока число не войдет в диапазон -128...127 и
> потом отнимается еще раз

---

В байте 8 бит: 00000000

Тип данных byte состоит из 1 байта: 00000000

Тип данных int состоит из 4 байтов: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Отсчёт ведётся справа налево: 4 байт, 3 байт, 2 байт, 1 байт

---

Кстати, диапазон типа byte может различаться в зависимости от языка, например:

Java byte = -128...127

C# byte = 0...255

---

К сути:

Число 257 с типом int в двоичном представлении: 00000000 00000000 0000000**1 00000001**

Усекаем int с числом 257 до byte(отбрасываем последние 3 байта) и получаем: **00000001**

Переводим **00000001** из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную и получаем **1**