# Оператор == и сравнение

Tags: java

**Переменные примитивных типов** состоят из битов и представляют свои значения, **ссылочные переменные** содержат биты, которые описывают способ получения объекта.

---

**Для сравнения двух примитивов применяйте оператор ==**

> Оператор == может быть использован для сравнения двух переменных
>   любого типа - он просто проверяет на соответствие их биты.

Выражение `if (a == b) { ... }` смотрит на биты внутри `a` и `b` и возвращает `true`, если они совпадают.

```
int a = 3;
byte b = 3;
if (a == b ) {...}
```

Но как проверяет на соответствие их биты. Если `int` 32 бита, а `byte` 8 бит? В данном примере `a` не должно было быть равно `b` потому что `int` и `byte` имеют разные биты

Проще говоря для примитивов оператор `==` сравнивает их значения это я знаю, но читая в книге про биты вообще ничего не понимаю. Объясните пожалуйста, если возможно визуально, заранее благодарю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я ничего не путаю, то при сравнении выполняется автоматическое приведение типов, то есть если это возможно то , обе переменные будут приведены к общему типу данных:
например если есть `byte b = 8` и `int i = 10`, то при их сравнении `b==i` будет автоматически произведено что-то вроде:

```
(int) b == i
```

Числа вообще хранятся в виде единичек и ноликов, то есть при преобразовании int i 257(000000...100000001) в byte i просто обрежутся все лишние байты слева и переменная i будет равна не 256(111111111), а (000000001)

Т.е. касательно вашего вопроса просто автоматически добавятся нулевые биты для переменной типа byte

Вообще чтобы понять эту тему вам просто нужно поподробнее почитать про явное и неявное Преобразования базовых типов данных и как оно вообще выполняется, вот пара ссылок:

1. https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.2.php
2. [Перевод int в byte?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960110/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-int-%D0%B2-byte)

Comment: А почему нулевые?

Comment: потому что цифры вообще сравниваются в двоичном виде, byte b = 8 это 00001000, а int b = 8 это 00000000...01000, написав "добавятся нулевые биты" я имел ввиду, что будет выполнено автоматическое преобразование к int и просто станет больше нулей слева